# WPF Binding Textbox to ViewModel

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, mvvm

I have a textbox that is bound to a property on my ViewModel called DatabaseFilter

here is the implementation of the property

```
public string DatabaseFilter {
    get { return _databaseFilter; }
    set { 
        _databaseFilter = value;
        FilterDatabases();
    }
}
```

as you can see, i am trying to trigger a filtering based on what is typed into the textbox.

The problem is, that the setter is triggered when the textbox loses focus. So typing into the textbox is not doing anything, until the user presses TAB.

Is it possible to make the binding update underling viewmodel with each key press via binding? I would like to avoid having to add key down/up events, to keep the UI/codebehind as clean as possible.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Set `UpdateSourceTrigger` on your TextBox to `PropertyChanged` (which defaults to `LostFocus`)

Comment: to all the people downvoting a perfectly valid answer: have the decency to at least paste a comment to say what you'd rather see improved, if you can't do it yourself

Answer (score 25):

You need to set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` property on your binding expression, e.g.

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=DatabaseFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
```

There are also different values available, like: `Explicit` - when you need to explicitly call update on binding; `LostFocus` - this is default for `TextBox`, updates binding after control looses focus.

You need to remember, that if your filtering action is executed on UI thread, filtering after each keystroke may not be wisest thing to do, since user experience may be seriously affected by delays created by this filtering. If you are positive, that you need to filter after each keystroke, be sure that filtering will be quick (e.g. there is only few items to filter), or that you will filter in background thread.

Answer (score 5):

Change your binding to update the source whenever the property changes:

`<TextBox Text="{Binding DatabaseFilter, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">`

Answer (score 4):

`UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged` should solve this issue for you

Answer (score 4):

Use the `Binding.UpdateSourceTrigger` property on your binding. The default update source trigger is focus loss. You can change it so that every time the text in the textbox changes the binding will happen.

see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.updatesourcetrigger.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Create a command in your VM "FilterDatabaseCommand", the bind the event "TextChanged" of the textbox to this command (use the EventToCommand behavior).

Or simply change your code to this :

```
public string DatabaseFilter {
    get { return _databaseFilter; }
    set { 
        if(_databaseFilter != value) {
            _databaseFilter = value;
            FilterDatabases();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks, although changing the property code won't do much as it is simply not being called until lost focus. creating command would work, but in my case, i prefer the simpler solution that doesn't require a command, just simple binding. went with above suggestion of changing UpdateSourceTrigger property and that did what i needed.